# android gcm registers on both emulator and phone but only receives notifications on emulator?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

As the title says, my emulator receives the notifications I type from the google server I implemented on my localhost:8080. But it doesn't receive them on my physical device. I checked and both the emulator and my phone are getting registered so I'm wondering if there's a setting I need on my phone to receive them??

Comment: Hello, if you using localhost, then its not work on physical device because device not support localhost properties. Its works for only emulator. Try to do on online server, then its work only.

Comment: Thank you! I need to setup an outside server then correct? Something like apache?

Comment: Ya, you have to use other then localhost, any server but bot localhost. Give upvote.